# change projection in an ascii (x,y,z) file

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, ascii, exogeography, mars

I am having an ASCII file (lat,long,depth) in the Mars projection. I need this file to be converted into WGS-84 projection. How can I do the conversion for the ASCII files.

Comment: Does it make sense to convert Mars coordinates into Earth WGS84 coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdalwarp to convert the raster.

`gdalwarp -a_srs "+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=3396190 +b=3396190 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 mars.asc mars_wgs84.tif`

I am not sure which Mars projection your data is in, but choose the appropriate parameters in the for -a_srs. See [Mars Map Projections](http://chrisherwig.org/hirise/Data%20Processing/2012/10/21/mars-map-projections/)